# Swift protocol ANY closure type

Tags: swift, types, closures

So I was trying to make my own swift "eval" function, and my approach is to make some sort of class that accepts operators and then when you submit it a string of operations it can eval it into another type. My first step was to make an operator class so I could store operators. My approach was to make an operator protocol that required a string representation of the operator, ex: "++" (so that the operator can be recognized when evaluating a string), and a function called operate that actually executes the operation
Here is the protocol I made:

```
protocol Operator {
    associatedtype returnType
    var id: String { get }
    var operate: (_ item: returnType) -> returnType { get }
}
```

Then, I went ahead and made a structure that conforms to Operator like so:

```
struct PrefixOperator<T>: Operator {
    var id: String
    var operate: (_ item: T) -> T
}
```

this worked as intended, however as I moved to make an infix operator which operates on two elements (for example: 5 - 3 were "-" is the operator)

```
struct InfixOperator<T>: Operator {
    var id: String
    var operate: (_ left: T, _right: T)
}
```

I get an error message saying it does not conform to the protocol.
I understand why it doesnt, and I think the solution is to make the protocol require any closure - let me just show you what I mean:

```
protocol Operator {
    associatedtype returnType
    var id: String { get }
    var operate: AnyClosure { get }
}
```

However, looking through the docs I cannot find a type that represents a closure of any sort
The answer Im looking for is if such a thing exists, and if it doesnt, I would really appreciate further guidance, maybe a tip from someone on how I could do this differently.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is currently no way in the Swift language to denote "this is a function of _any_ type" without also generalizing so much that it would be possible for other types to sneak in there. An approach like what @Zoro4rk suggests is likely your best bet — you can't _prevent_ arbitrary types from conforming to, say, `BinaryOperator`, but why would you (or someone else) conform an arbitrary type to the protocol? If that's not a sufficient guarantee, though, it would help to know why.

Comment: The only problem is if I use an associated type, I can't make a list of operators which is something I would like to do.

Comment: I know this doesn't help you now, but: that limitation of protocols with associated types will be going away in Swift 5.7: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md

Comment: When is swift 5.7 coming out?

Comment: It's scheduled to go out with Xcode 14 — so, likely within a few months. (But again, sadly, does not solve your problem right now.)

Comment: How you'd use that `AnyClosure`, in your case? Can you write some pseudocode, to help understand? BTW, the `InfixOperator` not conforming to the protocol is due to the way `operate` is declared in the protocol, so I'd say the problem is with the design of the solution, not necessarily the lack of an `AnyClosure`.

Comment: Hi, sorry that wasn't my problem. I know that it doesn't conform, the problem is that the protocol, Operator, might be extended by operators that have different function parameters - such as InfixOperator which needs 2 (example: x-y) - and PrefixOperator which has an operate function that only takes on parameter (example: new PrefixOperator("-") { -$0}

Comment: Well... a protocol defines a contract, so you're asking for a protocol than allows any kind of function calls on it? If that's your goal, then protocols are not the way to go, but you might have more luck with the dynamic member lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can define AnyClosure with associatedtype in protocol

```
protocol Operator {
    associatedtype AnyClosure
    var id: String { get }
    var operate: AnyClosure { get }
}

protocol UnaryOperator: Operator {
    associatedtype returnType
    var id: String { get }
    var operate: (_ item: returnType) -> returnType { get }
}

protocol BinaryOperator: Operator {
    associatedtype returnType
    var id: String { get }
    var operate: (_ left: returnType, _ right: returnType) -> returnType { get }
}

struct PrefixOperator<T>: UnaryOperator {
    var id: String
    var operate: (_ item: T) -> T
}

struct InfixOperator<T>: BinaryOperator {
    var id: String
    var operate: (_ left: T, _ right: T) -> T
}
```

OR

```
protocol Operator {
    associatedtype AnyClosure
    var id: String { get }
    var operate: AnyClosure { get }
}

struct PrefixOperator<T>: Operator {
    var id: String
    var operate: (_ item: T) -> T
}

struct InfixOperator<T>: Operator {
    var id: String
    var operate: (_ left: T, _ right: T) -> T
}
```

I hope it will be useful

Comment: I knew this. But then it doesnt have to be a closure, right?